# Select 2 records into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to combine 2 rows into one row using the following query but it still returns 2 records. Is there anyway I get it to to work with the single query? Thanks for any suggestions.

TABLE_A

```
+------+-------+----------+
| A_ID | EN_ID | COMMENTS |
+------+-------+----------+
|    2 |    10 | test     |
+------+-------+----------+
```

TABLE_B

```
+-------+--------+
| EN_ID | ADD_ID |
+-------+--------+
|    10 |    101 |
|    10 |    102 |
+-------+--------+
```

TABLE_C

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| ADD_ID | ADD_TYPE_ID |   street    |   city    |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|    101 |           1 | teststreet1 | citytest1 |
|    102 |           2 | teststreet2 | Citytest2 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Desired Result

```
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| EN_ID | COMMENTS |  street_1   |  city_1   |  street_2   |  city_2   |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|     3 | test     | teststreet1 | citytest1 | teststreet2 | Citytest2 |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Query

```
select    
    A.EN_ID, 
    A.COMMENTS, 
    C1.STREET as strret_1, 
    C1.CITY as city_1,  
    C2.STREET as strret_2, 
    C2.CITY as city_2  
from      
    TABLE_A A
left join 
    TABLE_B B ON
    B.EN_ID = A.EN_ID 
left join 
    TABLE_C C1 
    ON C1.ADD_ID = B.ADD_ID 
    and C1.ADD_TYPE_ID = 1
left join 
    TABLE_C C2 
    ON  C2.ADD_ID = B.ADD_ID 
    and C2.ADD_TYPE_ID = 2
    and A.A_ID = 2;
```

Comment: `and where C2.ADD_TYPE_ID = 2` No, this is not a thing... Remove the `where` from this statement

Comment: I removed it. still I have the same result.

Comment: How are you getting EN_ID = 3.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick

```
DECLARE @tA TABLE (A_ID INT, EN_ID INT, COMMENTS VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @tA VALUES
(2,10,'test')

DECLARE @tB TABLE (EN_ID INT, ADD_ID INT)
INSERT INTO @tB VALUES
(10,101),
(10,102)

DECLARE @tC TABLE (ADD_ID INT, ADD_TYPE_ID INT, Street VARCHAR(255), City VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @tC VALUES
(101,1,'teststreet1','citytest1'),        
(102,2,'teststreet2','Citytest2') 

SELECT A.EN_ID, A.COMMENTS, MAX(C1.Street) AS Street1, MAX(C1.City) AS City1, MAX(C2.Street) AS Street2, MAX(C2.City) AS City2
FROM @tA AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tB AS B ON B.EN_ID = A.EN_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM @tC WHERE ADD_TYPE_ID = 1) AS C1 ON C1.ADD_ID = B.ADD_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM @tC WHERE ADD_TYPE_ID = 2) AS C2 ON C2.ADD_ID = B.ADD_ID 
GROUP BY A.EN_ID, A.COMMENTS
```

Result

```
EN_ID  COMMENTS  Street1      City1      Street2      City2
----------------------------------------------------------------
10     test      teststreet1  citytest1  teststreet2  Citytest2
```

Comment: Don't be shy in adding your DDL that you used for your table variables so others can run locally. Though this doesn't match the OP expected results, it's likely the most correct.

Answer (score 0):

### Edited

Try something like this:

```
SELECT a.en_id, a.comments, c1.street AS street_1, c1.city AS city_1,
       c2.street AS street_2, c2.city AS city_2  
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN table_b b1 ON b1.en_id = a.en_id 
  LEFT JOIN table_c c1 ON c1.add_id = b1.add_id AND c1.add_type_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN table_b b2 ON b2.en_id = a.en_id AND b1.add_id <> b2.add_id
  LEFT JOIN table_c c2 ON c2.add_id = b2.add_id AND c2.add_type_id = 2
  WHERE a.a_id = 2 AND ( b1.add_id IS NOT NULL OR b2.add_id IS NOT NULL )
```

This last line also could be:

```
  WHERE a.a_id = 2 AND NOT ( b1.add_id IS NULL AND b2.add_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: This query still returns 2 records. table_b has 2 records. it may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Another faster way :

```
SELECT    
    A.EN_ID, 
    A.COMMENTS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.ADD_TYPE_ID = 1 THEN C.city ELSE '' END) AS city1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.ADD_TYPE_ID = 1 THEN C.street ELSE '' END) AS street1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.ADD_TYPE_ID = 2 THEN C.city ELSE '' END) AS city2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.ADD_TYPE_ID = 2 THEN C.street ELSE '' END) AS street2
FROM      
    TABLE_A A
left join TABLE_B as B ON (B.EN_ID = A.EN_ID) 
left join TABLE_C AS C ON (C.ADD_ID = B.ADD_ID)
GROUP BY A.EN_ID, A.COMMENTS
```

Note : you may have warnings if C.city or C.street have some NULL values. If so use ISNULL(C.city,'') and ISNULL(C.street,'') syntax...